# How Do I Specify a Column Name for a Default Constraint?

Tags: sql-server

I know I can specify it inline like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
(
    Id INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable_Id PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Created DATETIME NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_MyTable_Created DEFAULT GETDATE()
)
```

But I'd like to put all my constraints at the end of the table definition to keep them separate. I can't seem to find out how to name the column for the default constraint if I put it at the end of the table definition. I can do it with primary/foreign keys and unique constraints, but don't know how to specify the column name with a default constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
(
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    Created DATETIME NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable_Id PRIMARY KEY( Id ),
    CONSTRAINT DF_MyTable_Created DEFAULT GETDATE()
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it separate with ALTER TABLE ADD..... syntax

like this

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
(
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    Created DATETIME NOT NULL

)
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ADD CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable_Id PRIMARY KEY( Id ),
CONSTRAINT DF_MyTable_Created DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR Created
GO
```

Comment: I'd rather do it inline than altering the table.

Comment: in that case you would have to do your first option

Comment: I take it it's just not possible for a default constraint?